# Does Android do All the things that Java can do?

Tags: java, android

I know android not includes all of java's library.
but I just want to know can I add the jars to replace with  some of java's lib. not included in Android?
thank you all in advance.

Comment: What libraries (JAR files) do you want to add? What functionality do you require?