# Can all java packages be used in android programming?

Tags: java, android

I would like to know whether i can use the java packages i use in programming for android programming.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4648709/does-android-do-all-the-things-that-java-can-do?rq=1

Comment: y closed this question? what  was wrong in it? people who have time are spending time to close others questions:(:(

Comment: thanks for your time.. For helping me. i just needed a yes or no.

Comment: @AamirKhan its closed because there is far too less research put before asking. Searching java on android gives you a wiki page that gives the answer